# Sharepoint mutliple Panel Panes automatically default to first item

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I currently have a website in which there are multiple Preview Pane view tables.  After some searching I found how to get the default view to show the first item.  However, it only works for the first preview pane, and I have several on the page.  I am new at jquery.  I believe I need to loop through all Preview Panes on the page and run the below script, but I cannot figure out how to get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the script I have so far:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(
 function ()
 {
        $("div.ms-ppleft table tr td.ms-vb-title").first().trigger("onfocus");
}
)</script>
```

Comment: `.first()` select first `td.ms-vb-title` in your selector. If you want  to trigger event to all `.ms-vb-title` remove `.first()`. Your code should changed to `$("div.ms-ppleft table tr td.ms-vb-title").trigger("onfocus")`

Comment: This worked!  Thank you so much.  I can't believe it was that easy.